# Is there a way to add a aggregated/calculated field (concat) to a Doctrine entity?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a USER entity, which countains two fields : firstname and lastname.

I would like to know how I can add a virtual column called fullname (firstname + ' ' + upper(lastname)) to my entity.

I have read already the Doctrine documentation about aggregated fields but I am not sure how to use this in my context.

I don't want to add a concat and upper formula to every DQL I will launch on my users but I would like to add a computed field once in my entity. Doing a PHP getter is not a solution.

```
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="[user]")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="string")
     */
    private $lastname;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string")
     */
    private $firstname;
}
```

if I add an aggregate field like this to my entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $fullName='';

public getFullName(){
     return $this->firstname . ' ' . $this->lastname;
}
```

my code crashes when I call find() or findAll() on a User entity (invalid column name)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's the wrong approach do do that "magic". If you need that fullname field only for the view, you can use your getter as it is. In case you need it persisted, you should concatinate the first- and lastname string in its setters and set the fullname property. in this case, your getter should return that property.